# msgget() function always return 0

Tags: c, linux

I'm making a simple message program with C in LINUX.
I want to make two queues.

In main(), I made message queues like below.
excute as like ./a.out 123 321

```
/* create message queues */
int rcv_queue;
int snd_queue;

if(rcv_queue = msgget( (key_t) *argv[1], IPC_CREAT|0666) == -1) {
    perror("receiver msgget() failed\n");
    exit(1);
}

if(snd_queue = msgget( (key_t) *argv[2], IPC_CREAT|0666) == -1) {
    perror("sender msgget() failed\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

How can I make > 0 ?

Comment: Both of your if statements have some syntax issues for C.  Can you explain more how this is supposed to evaluate? if(snd_queue = msgget( (key_t) *argv[2], IPC_CREAT|0666) == -1)

Comment: Does your compiler give you any warnings? Always compile with a healthy set of warnings enabled (`-Wall -Wextra` for gcc and clang)

Comment: Did you look at `ipcs`? What values are you using for `argv`? Note that, usually, you either pass IPC_PRIVATE or use a key like 0x01020304 [and 0x01020305]. Note that you really only need _one_ queue as you can have each participant wait on a different `mtype` value. Say you assigned 1 to program A and assigned 2 to program B, A waits on `mtype==1` and B waits on `mtype==2`. To send: `A->B`, use `mtype=2` and `B->A` use `mtype=1`. In the past, I've written a comercial shipping product that had 50 waiters on the single/same queue

Comment: I wouldn't use `argv` [as I've mentioned], but I think you want (e.g.) `argv[1]` and _not_ `*argv[1]` Both calls are returning _zero_ which means **SUCCESS**. They are _both_ succeeding but are opening the _same_ key. If the keys were different, 1st call would return 0 and 2nd call would return 1 [just like file descriptors]. Once again, 0 _is_ a valid return value.

Comment: @CraigEstey The only thing that can be said about `msgget()`'s return value here is that it isn't -1.

Comment: OMG it was the problem that I didn't prenthesize... Thank you so much